# Hierarchical grouping in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

I'm pretty new to WPF, and I can't manage to find a proper way to implement something like this.

Given this object

```
public class Parameter
{   
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Group {get; set;}
}
```

I am succesfully displaying a list of Parameter in a DataGrid.

The Group property contains a string in this format "A/B/C/D"

I would like to have "hierarchical grouping", so that A is a group, B is a group belonging to A and so on.

I've seen it's possible to group based on a given property, but I can't find a way to group like I need.

Is it possible ?

Comment: So you need to group your items inside list of parameters or inside datagrid?

Comment: I need to be able to display groups in the DataGrid. 
For instance, if I have two parameters with Group="A" and Group="A/B", the DataGrid should display a group A containing both the first parameter and the group B with the second parameter.
I hope it's clear.

Comment: @LorenzoSantoro i wouldn't go with grouping .
But i need first to understand your needs .

Come here please : 

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: @LorenzoSantoro also search for a listview with columns